# installing scipy on mac 10.6.5

Tags: python, scipy

I have got a MacBook Pro(10.6.5) and trying to install scipy using pip. Please note that I am very new to python world. BTW, I have used the following command:

```
pip install --user scipy
```

and I have got the following errors:

```
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /Users/hk3/build/scipy

    Exception information:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/hk3/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg                                                     /pip/basecommand.py", line 104, in main
   status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Users/hk3/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg/pip/commands /install.py", line 245, in run
   requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,  bundle=self.bundle)
    File "/Users/hk3/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 1009, in prepare_files
   req_to_install.run_egg_info()
```

File "/Users/hk3/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg/pip/req.py", line 225, in run_egg_info
       command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
       File "/Users/hk3/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.6.egg/pip/**init**.py", line 256, in call_subprocess
       % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
        InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in       /Users/hk3/build/scipy

I will really appreciate if someone can point me what I am doing wrong!
thanks

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092306/how-to-install-scipy-with-pip-on-mac-mountain-lion-os-x-v10-8/14315132#14315132 . I recommend using samueljohn's homebrew 'tap' to install scipy.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success with the Enthought python distribution for Mac.  Installed on 10.7.4

The subscription version is described here:
http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php

The free version is described here:
http://www.enthought.com/products/epd_free.php