# How to install Scipy with pip on Mac Mountain Lion OS X v10.8

Tags: macos, scipy, pip, osx-mountain-lion

I'm having serious difficulty installing Scipy with pip on Mountain Lion.
I've tried:

```
sudo pip install -e git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy#egg=scipy-dev
```

As suggested in various places on the web.

This leads to errors like:

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/tmp//ccC2HLVs.out
```

and several warnings (I assume not serious) before the errors.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't installed Mountain Lion yet, but by experience, I'd suggest to stay away from `pip` in a first step. Download the sources and compile them yourself with `python setup.py install --user`. The `--user` flag will force the installation in `~/.local`, no need for a `sudo`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pip has difficulties with scipy on OS X in general. It is not trivial to install from the sources, so I advise against it. In OS X you have a few better options:

- [Scipy superpack](http://fonnesbeck.github.com/ScipySuperpack/), a bunch of precompiled binaries
- [Enthought Canopy](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) (free or another) has already everything you'll need (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, etc.)
- [Anaconda](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/), a free scientific python distribution with probably all the packages you'll ever need.
- [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org), a comprehensive and flexible package manager that allows you to install and maintain a python distribution
- [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), another popular package manager for OS X

Comment: I was hoping to do this through pip partly to keep control of my environment. I seem to recall that is was possible with a previous version of OSX. I'm partly confused by why the suggestions of installing the dev version (which presumably works for others) isn't working for me...

Comment: @arlogb From the [scipy webpage](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/BuildingGeneral): "Also note that the use of pip and especially easy_install is not recommended, as these tools often have problems where the standard python setup.py install does not."

Comment: This is a bit late, but with regards to installing via PIP, it seems to work well for me, so long as I install the pseudo-optional requirements first. In general, I have to do

    # Install numpy and PIL first, so PIP doesn't
    # mess up the scipy install.
    pip install numpy pil
    pip install -r requirements.txt # containing scipy

The relevent PIP Issue is [Github #25](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/25)

Answer (score 18):

Scipy is also available now via a homebrew tap. If you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed:

```
brew tap samueljohn/python
brew install scipy
```

See more info here: [homebrew-python](https://web.archive.org/web/20130926164444/https://github.com/samueljohn/homebrew-python)

Comment: In addition, I needed to first use Homebrew's Python ('brew install python; brew link --overwrite python'), and after the tap and scipy install (which are successful): 'pip install python-dateutil'.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what worked for me for pip installing matplotlib and scipy inside a virtual environment (Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks):

```
# See George's answer above
brew update
brew upgrade
brew install gfortran 

# See http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/macosx.html (the link Nathan Gould posted above)
export CXX=g++-5.1
export CC=gcc-5.1
export FFLAGS=-ff2c
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5.1
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++ /usr/bin/g++-5.1

pip install matplotlib
pip install scipy
```

matplot lib installed quickly, but scipy took a long time.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to what @Anton I. Sipos said. I had the Enthought package installed but had issues with upgrading it, so I decided to go with a clean install using *Homebrew*. Unfortunately just performing the tap and install didn't work well for me. So on searching a bit I found an [issue](https://github.com/samueljohn/homebrew-python/issues/1) on GitHub that *samualjohn* addressed and worked for me:

```
brew remove python
rm -rf /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages # it's save to delete this!
brew install python
pip install nose
brew install numpy
brew install scipy
```

The problem was clearly conflicts in the site-packages that the Enthought uninstall instructions did not cover.

NOTE: I had to install *matplotlib* with *pip*.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues installing scipy on OSX 10.9 Mavericks as well. What solved it for me is the following:

```
sudo pip list
```

was showing numpy, thus I did:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade numpy
```

Afterwards

```
brew list
```

was showing gfortran. I made sure I had the latest version by

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

but

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

was failing with a weird fortran error.
Thus I uninstalled it and reinstalled it

```
sudo brew install gfortran
sudo brew uninstall gfortran
```

and to my great surprise

```
sudo pip install scipy
```

worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

I recently also had trouble getting scipy to install on a virtualenv. My problem was that gfortran was not seen properly. I used macports `sudo port install gcc48` and created a symlink to just gfortran by:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-4.8 /opt/local/bin/gfortran
```

After that, `pip install scipy` worked without any errors on my virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Installing scipy on Mac OS X with pip is possible! You will need the right C and Fortran compilers on your system to set up scipy. This page should help you:

http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/macosx.html

Once you have done that, you should be able to install with `pip install scipy`.

As an additional troubleshooting note, you might need to create a symlink to your compiler so that the setup process can find it. A previous poster @biophetik gave an example of how to do this.

Also, I already had numpy installed in my virtual environment when I installed scipy. I'm not positive whether/how one depends on the other.

Answer (score 1):

On Mavericks the following works (might also work on other versions):

If you haven't already, install `pip`

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Then install/update `scipy`

```
sudo pip install scipy -U
```

For some reason `pip` installs `scipy` to

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

and does not remove the older version in

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7//Extras/lib/python/scipy/
```

So just remove the old version and it works. Print the version number:

```
python -c "import scipy; print scipy.__version__"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tryed everything: pip, macports,easy_install,... with Mac OS El Captain. The only thing that worked for me was brew:

```
$ brew install scipy
```

After that, it will ask you to follow the instructions bellow:

```
$ brew link --overwrite numpy
$ mkdir -p /Users/adrieljr/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
$ echo 'import sys; sys.path.insert(1, "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/adrieljr/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```