# can't install scipy on mac OS X

Tags: macos, python-2.7, scipy, pip

I have numpy and matplot installed and working properly with python 2.7, but when I use pip to install scipy, I get this error.

```
numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config.PkgNotFound: Could not find file(s)        ['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/lib/npy-pkg-config/npymath.ini']

 ----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in    /var/folders/61/dpn0d5p51z19g5vypnmh3vfh0000gn/T/pip-build/scipy
```

Comment: There are a lot of dependencies and you are probably missing something. The following resource may be able to help you: [Installing Python, virtualenv, NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib and IPython on Lion or Mountain Lion](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/).

Comment: I added a bounty to this. I'm using Mountain Lion, Homebrew, pip, and virtualenv. I don't want to use MacPorts. I want the problem solved as close to the "core" of the problem as possible -- which I think is in NumPy.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092306/how-to-install-scipy-with-pip-on-mac-mountain-lion-os-x-v10-8/14315132#14315132 . I recommend using homebrew and samueljohn's 'taps' to install scipy.

Comment: If it's `pip`, there should be a debug log mentioned at the end of the output that should give more information.

Answer (score 9):

There is no end to the amount of grief that you can run into when trying to install numpy, scipy, and matplotlib on Mac OS X. If you want to stay on the bleeding edge I would suggest downloading the git repositories and building each one.

If you don't need to be on the bleeding edge I would suggest, following the instructions on the SciPy web site:

https://scipy.org/install/#macos

Finally, there is the great work that Chris Fonnesbeck: At https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack

The Fonnesbeck method has never failed for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also was not able to install scipy using pip. However an option that has worked for me was using the .dmg package [provided by scipy.org](http://scipy.org/install.html).

Important: you will have to update to the latest version of python in your Mac OS. That is, you can still use the Python 2.7, however it is necessary to update to the latest build which you can download at python.org.

Answer (score -1):

I could suggest you to use some package manager for Mas OS X (for example macports). Using a kind of such system could avoid you from such things like manual resolving of dependencies, and so on.

Comment: I'm using homebrew which, generally speaking, has been getting a lot more traction than MacPorts.